# Remove "et al" from one in-line citation

Tags: bibliographies

I have a bibtex entry containing an author list of the form

```
author = {{Spiffly Collaboration} and {Smith}, S. and {Jones}, E. and {Williams}, C. and {Green}, P. and {Foobar}, B. and {Bloggs}, J. K.}
```

In my document I would like to cite this entry as follows:

```
This research has made use of the Spiffly software package (Spiffly Collaboration, 2010)
```

However, it always comes out as "Spiffly Collaboration et al, 2010". The "et al." should not be there. The bibliography should contain the full list list of authors, so I cannot simply edit the authors out of the bib file. I also need the bit inside the brackets to be an actual cite, because for all my other citations clicking on the year takes the reader to the bibliography.

Is there a good way of achieving this?

Comment: Not an answer, but just a remark: the authors' family names should not be in braces; an organization name like “Spiffly Collaboration” is a different thing.

Comment: @egreg- these come from computer generated bibtex entries, and I assume the reason is to prevent people with double-barrelled surnames being cited wrong. It would be incorrect to cite, say, Ralph Vaughan Williams as Williams, R. V.

Comment: That should be `author={Vaughan Williams, Ralph}`, very simple.

Comment: Well, in that case, I don't know why they do it that way. But since it's a standard imposed on me from outside I won't go back and mess with it.

Comment: Do you have the option of using `biblatex`.  In combination with `biber`, it can modify entries on the fly.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Or use `shortauthor` in that case?

Comment: Computer-generated `.bib` files are hardly ever usable as-is. At least, the ones I get aren't. If you get files from a standard source, just write a script to make the adjustments for you each time. (I use `sed` and `gawk` but no doubt you need something else if you are on Windows.)

Comment: @cfr Yes, that would be one field one could use in such a scheme.